# Create a for Loop on a multiple regression utilizing Pandas (StatsModels)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, linear-regression

I am performing a multiple regression for 50 states to determine the life expectancy per state based on several variables.  Currently I have my dataset filtered to only Maine, and I want to know if there is a way to create a For Loop to go through the whole State Column and perform a regression for each state.  This would be more efficient than creating 50 filters.  Any help would be great!

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.formula.api as ols

df = pd.read_excel(C:/Users/File1.xlsx, sheet_name = 'States')

dfME = df[(df[State] == "Maine")]

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

dfME.head()

model = smf.ols(Life Expectancy ~ Race + Age + Weight + C(Pets), data = dfME) 
modelfit = model.fit()
modelfit.summary
```

Comment: I would recommend something like `df.groupby('State').apply(my_model)` where `my_model` is a function that handles your modeling and returns the `modelfit.summary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
###### Assuming rest of your code is ok I am sharing a strategy for the loop and storing model outputs:
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
state_modelfit_summary = {}
states = df['State'].unique() # As you only need to loop once for each state
for st in states:
    dfME = df[(df['State'] == st)]     
    model = smf.ols(Life Expectancy ~ Race + Age + Weight + C(Pets), data = dfME) 
    modelfit = model.fit()
    # Store output in a dictionary with state name as key
    state_modelfit_summary[st] = modelfit.summary
```